# Error in launching ansible playbook with roles

Tags: ansible, roles

trying to do playbook:

```
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: no
  roles: 
    - update_win
```

update_win mail.yml:

```
- name: Create Auto_deploy_temp folder on remoter host
  win_file:
    path: {{ disk }}\Auto_deploy_temp
    state: directory
```

and vars in group vars file win.yml:

```
disk: 'c:'
```

but getting out:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/roles/update_win/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 19, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  win_file:
  path: {{ disk }}\Auto_deploy_temp
                  ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"

can u help me with this issue?
```

P.S.: earlier i've launched some similar code, but there were no vars in the start of path expression, only in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide path: "{{ disk }}\Auto_deploy_temp"

**Update**
Create a new var as path_dir: \Auto_deploy_temp, and use
path: "{{disk}}{{path_dir}}"
or
path: "{{ disk }}\\Auto_deploy_temp"

Comment: it's the same: ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unknown escape character

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/roles/update_win/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 22, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

Comment: may be there is some problem with vars, not syntax

Comment: Please try to store Auto_deploy_temp to a variable as path: Auto_deploy_temp, and then use  path: "{{ disk }}\{{path}}" or try to give the path directly once. path: C:\Auto_deploy_temp

Comment: "{{ disk }}\{{ auto_deploy_folder }}" - in that case it doesn't work, but when i made variable auto_deploy_folder = \Auto_deploy_temp - in that case it was "{{ disk }}{{ auto_deploy_folder }}" and it's ok. Thank you very much! but can you tell, in what part of code there was a mistake and why? is it bug with vars or something?

Comment: I feel it is the problem with quotes. Or it might be because of \(backslash) which ansible thinks as an escape character.

Comment: find the problem: backslashes+quotes ( "{{ disk }}\\somefolder")

Answer (score 0):

Escape '\'

```
win_file:
path: {{ disk }}\\Auto_deploy_temp
```